# How to prevent Dynamics CRM 2015 from creating an opportunity when a lead is qualified?

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, dynamics-crm

Requirements when clicking the `Qualify` button in the Lead entity form:

- Do not create an Opportunity
- Retain original CRM qualify-lead JavaScript
- Detect duplicates and show duplicate detection form for leads
- Redirect to contact, either merged or created version, when done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Pawel Gradecki already posted how to prevent CRM from creating an Opportunity when a Lead is qualified. The tricky part is to make the UI/client refresh or redirect to the contact, as CRM does nothing if no Opportunity is created.

Before we begin, Pawel pointed out that

> some code is not supported, so be careful during upgrades

I don't have experience with any other versions than CRM 2015, but he writes that there are better ways to do this in CRM 2016, so upgrade if you can. This is a fix that's easy to implement now and easy to remove after you've upgraded.

Add a JavaScript-resource and register it in the Lead form's OnSave event. The code below is in TypeScript. TypeScript-output (js-version) is at the end of this answer.

```
function OnSave(executionContext: ExecutionContext | undefined) {
    let eventArgs = executionContext && executionContext.getEventArgs()
    if (!eventArgs || eventArgs.isDefaultPrevented() || eventArgs.getSaveMode() !== Xrm.SaveMode.qualify)
        return

    // Override the callback that's executed when the duplicate detection form is closed after selecting which contact to merge with.
    // This callback is not executed if the form is cancelled.
    let originalCallback = Mscrm.LeadCommandActions.performActionAfterHandleLeadDuplication
    Mscrm.LeadCommandActions.performActionAfterHandleLeadDuplication = (returnValue) => {
        originalCallback(returnValue)
        RedirectToContact()
    }

    // Because Opportunities isn't created, and CRM only redirects if an opportunity is created upon lead qualification,
    // we have to write custom code to redirect to the contact instead
    RedirectToContact()
}

// CRM doesn't tell us when the contact is created, since its qualifyLead callback does nothing unless it finds an opportunity to redirect to.
// This function tries to redirect whenever the contact is created
function RedirectToContact(retryCount = 0) {
    if (retryCount === 10)
        return Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Could not redirect you to the contact. Perhaps something went wrong while CRM tried to create it. Please try again or contact the nerds in the IT department.")

    setTimeout(() => {
        if ($("iframe[src*=dup_warning]", parent.document).length)
            return // Return if the duplicate detection form is visible. This function is called again when it's closed

        let leadId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()
        $.getJSON(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + `/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/LeadSet(guid'${leadId}')?$select=ParentContactId`)
            .then(r => {
                if (!r.d.ParentContactId.Id)
                    return RedirectToContact(retryCount + 1)

                Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("contact", r.d.ParentContactId.Id)
            })
            .fail((_, __, err) => Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(`Something went wrong. Please try again or contact the IT-department.\n\nGuru meditation:\n${err}`))
    }, 1000)
}
```

TypeScript definitions:

```
declare var Mscrm: Mscrm

interface Mscrm {
    LeadCommandActions: LeadCommandActions
}

interface LeadCommandActions {
    performActionAfterHandleLeadDuplication: { (returnValue: any): void }
}

declare var Xrm: Xrm

interface Xrm {
    Page: Page
    SaveMode: typeof SaveModeEnum
    Utility: Utility
}

interface Utility {
    alertDialog(message: string): void
    openEntityForm(name: string, id?: string): Object
}

interface ExecutionContext {
    getEventArgs(): SaveEventArgs
}

interface SaveEventArgs {
    getSaveMode(): SaveModeEnum
    isDefaultPrevented(): boolean
}

interface Page {
    context: Context
    data: Data
}

interface Context {
    getClientUrl(): string
}

interface Data {
    entity: Entity
}

interface Entity {
    getId(): string
}

declare enum SaveModeEnum {
    qualify
}
```

TypeScript-output:

```
function OnSave(executionContext) {
    var eventArgs = executionContext && executionContext.getEventArgs();
    if (!eventArgs || eventArgs.isDefaultPrevented() || eventArgs.getSaveMode() !== Xrm.SaveMode.qualify)
        return;
    var originalCallback = Mscrm.LeadCommandActions.performActionAfterHandleLeadDuplication;
    Mscrm.LeadCommandActions.performActionAfterHandleLeadDuplication = function (returnValue) {
        originalCallback(returnValue);
        RedirectToContact();
    };
    RedirectToContact();
}
function RedirectToContact(retryCount) {
    if (retryCount === void 0) { retryCount = 0; }
    if (retryCount === 10)
        return Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Could not redirect you to the contact. Perhaps something went wrong while CRM tried to create it. Please try again or contact the nerds in the IT department.");
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($("iframe[src*=dup_warning]", parent.document).length)
            return;
        var leadId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
        $.getJSON(Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + ("/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/LeadSet(guid'" + leadId + "')?$select=ParentContactId"))
            .then(function (r) {
            if (!r.d.ParentContactId.Id)
                return RedirectToContact(retryCount + 1);
            Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("contact", r.d.ParentContactId.Id);
        })
            .fail(function (_, __, err) { return Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Something went wrong. Please try again or contact the IT-department.\n\nGuru meditation:\n" + err); });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I must admit I'm disappointed, I thought that you would present nice solution which nobody figured out yet, but instead this is unsupported JavaScript (because you are using jQuery and getting some DOM information). It's exactly the same as I mentioned in comment (but I did not update my answer, because the solution was too ugly for me, so I just left it as a comment) you just added unsupported handling of the duplicate dialog :/

Comment: I'm sorry it's not the solution you had hoped for. There will never be a pretty way to deal with not creating opportunities unless Microsoft releases a patch. Having gone through all the lead-related js, this is the best (of my knowledge) you can do. I didn't find any js that supported the duplicate detection form on the web, so I hope this can be of use to others who are stuck with 2015 as I am. It's easy to rewrite the code into native js if that's your thing :)

Comment: In this case I could have spent time on creating a custom qualify button, that handled duplication by itself. But in Microsoft's js, quite a few things happen behind the scene that I'd rather no implement on my own. This custom behavior could also be completely removed in 2016, which you say have much better support for avoiding opportunities. So this gets the job done with a minimal amount of code, that is trivial to remove when upgrading. Wouldn't you a agree that an easy-to-remove implementation, that gets the job done, is better than nothing?

Comment: I think my research is pretty thorough, but I'll gladly mark your answer as the right one if you can prove me wrong by linking to someone who have a similar or better solution.

Comment: Unsupported customizations are usually simple, that's why they are tempting :) Maybe I'm biased in some way, as I dealt and deal with many, many different deployments of CRM, since 4.0, and unsupported things were always problematic during upgrades, migrations and even sometimes Microsoft refused help because "system was not used properly". I mean it's only some piece of code and if you understand it and you use it right, then it's up to you. You look like a guy who knows what he's doing :) But many people are just copy-pasting things from Internet and are making some unsupported nightmares...

Comment: I will not give you a better link, you probably spent many hours resolving this issue, so I will not even try to search. I just wanted to point out that this is unsupported, so that people with less CRM experience would know. Your answer would be better if you would simply add a short information that some code is not supported, so be careful during upgrades (think about people who will come after us to this thread :)). Anyway you should mark your answer as it covers all bullet points. From me +1 for TypeScript and discussion (which is forbidden on SO, I guess :))

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to create a plugin running on Pre-Validation for message "QualifyLead". In this plugin you simply have to set CreateOpportunity input property to false. So it would look like:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    context.InputParameters["CreateOpportunity"] = false;
}
```

Or you can go with more fancy way:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    var qualifyRequest = new QualifyLeadRequest();
    qualifyRequest.Parameters  = context.InputParameters;
    qualifyRequest.CreateOpportunity = false;
}
```

Remember that it should be Pre-Validation to work correctly. Doing it like that allows you to remain with existing "Qualify" button, without any JavaScript modifications.

Comment: Nice with the more fancy way! It's close, but you're not redirected to the contact.

Comment: But this is exactly why I'm looking forward to share the part that redirects to the contact tomorrow. I'll just expand on your answer, as you've already posted the first part, with a cool way to initialize a QualifyLeadRequest I didn't know existed.

Comment: Looking forward to it, the only way I know is custom JS for on save event on Lead looking for savemode == 16 and then waiting some time and retrieve the qualified lead (and in this case get id of contact and open it's form). But I'm not a fan of that design, thankfully in CRM 2016 we can use web API and all that things are no longer needed :)

Comment: That is also a part of the solution, which I agree is not that pretty. There's no other way though, because CRM does nothing if the returned entities from the QualifyLeadRequest doesn't contain an Opportunity. Will be at work soon so I can grab the code.

Comment: I would have included that in my answer but I misread the second bullet point, I thought that you don't want to do any custom JavaScript at all.

Comment: I will accept your answer if your JS supports the lead duplicate form as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a fully functional and supported solution posted over at our Thrives blog: https://www.thrives.be/dynamics-crm/functional/lead-qualification-well-skip-that-opportunity.

Basically we combine the plugin modification as mentioned by Pawel with a Client Side redirect (using only supported JavaScript) afterwards:

```
function RefreshOnQualify(eventContext) {
    if (eventContext != null && eventContext.getEventArgs() != null) {
        if (eventContext.getEventArgs().getSaveMode() == 16) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false).then(function () {
                    var contactId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("parentcontactid").getValue();
                    if (contactId != null && contactId.length > 0) {
                        Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(contactId[0].entityType, contactId[0].id)
                    }
                }, function (error) { console.log(error) });;
            }, 1500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how this takes the duplicate detection form into account?

Comment: What happens if it takes more than 1.5 seconds to qualify the lead?

Comment: All technicalities aside, if qualifying a lead takes more than 1.5 seconds, I do think there is something wrong in the flow :-). However indeed, theoretically it is possible that the qualify would take longer than 1.5 seconds. I imagine the scenario in which data is synchronized with an external system might be a scenario where it can happen. In that case the refresh would not be executed.